# How to force Nsight Eclipse to use an older version of gcc/g++?

Tags: gcc, makefile, cuda, eclipse-cdt, nsight

I'm trying to migrate an existing C/C++ CUDA project into Nsight Eclipse. I'm using a manually written makefile to build the project, however I am getting the following error:

```
#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supported!
```

I previously had this error when I was using just a makefile outside of Nsight, however I fixed it by creating symlinks to gcc-4.9 and g++-4.9 in /usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin. This does not work for Nsight.

Here is my makefile (NOTE: I've set the CUDA_HOME environment variable inside Nsight):

```
NVCC          := nvcc

MODULES       := FA_kernels FD_kernels MEM_kernels MOD_kernels .
SRC_DIR       := $(MODULES)
BUILD_DIR     := $(addprefix build/,$(MODULES))

SRC           := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.cu))
OBJ           := $(patsubst %.cu,build/%.o,$(SRC))
HEADERS       := headers $(CUDA_HOME)/include $(CUDA_HOME)/samples/common/inc
INCLUDES      := $(addprefix -I,$(HEADERS))


build/%.o: %.cu
    $(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: all checkdirs clean

all: checkdirs build/lem

build/lem: $(OBJ)
    $(NVCC) $^ -o $@ -lgdal


checkdirs: $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @rm -rf build
```

Is there a way I can force Nsight to use gcc-4.9 and g++-4.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume based on your question text you have imported this as a makefile project.

In that case, one option would be to change the first line in your makefile to something like this:

```
NVCC          := nvcc -ccbin /path/to/gcc
```

You can read more about this option in the [nvcc documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications)

This would effect this change just for this project/makefile, not for all projects or all of eclipse/nsight

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the immediate problem. I'm getting linker errors now and I don't get why, but I guess that is a different question...